# Como relacionar la huella touch id con un usuario

Tags: swift, objective-c, touchid

¿Cómo puedo relacionar la huella dactilar con un usuario y contraseña? Es decir, yo puedo saber que esa huella dactilar es buena y la tengo registrada en el móvil, pero si ese móvil es compartido y tengo varias huellas registradas, ¿dentro de mi app cómo sé a qué usuario pertenece esa huella?

Digamos que con la huella A registro al usuario pepe en la app, ¿pero con la huella B cómo sé si también es el usuario pepe o si sería un usuario nuevo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede relacionar una huella almacenada en un dispositivo con un usuario y una contraseña. Para ello, debes importar el framework LocalAuthentication.framework y utilizar los métodos de éste. Para más información mirar el siguiente enlace que proporciona la documentación de Apple:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/localauthentication

Por otra parte, para relacionar la huella con un usuario y una contraseña utilizaría Keychain para guardar ambos en el sitio seguro del dispositivo. Apple nos proporciona un wrapper (puedes incluirlo con Cocoapods a través de este enlace: https://cocoapods.org/pods/KeychainItemWrapper) para poder implementar las operaciones con este framework. Previamente tendrás que importar el framework Security.framework en las opciones del proyecto.

A continuación adjunto un ejemplo de cómo utilizar TouchID con Keychain.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/KeychainTouchID/Introduction/Intro.html

Por último, contestando a tu última pregunta: No, no es posible detectar entre diferentes huellas almacenadas en un dispositivo. El framework de TouchID lo que hace es detectar huellas y devolver success en caso de que la huella coincida con las almacenadas y registradas en tu dispositivo o error, en caso contrario.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 3):

A nivel de sistema operativo **no es posible diferenciar entre varios usuarios**, por lo que no tienes opción de saber si las huellas registradas pertenecen a personas distintas realmente.

Puedes tener X huellas registradas (de tantas personas como quieras), pero en el momento de solicitar la autenticación mediante **Touch ID** el sistema **te indicará si la huella es válida o no la tiene registrada**. No te ofrece diferenciación alguna por qué persona física la ha registrado, asume que son todas de la misma. (Hasta que se implementen los perfiles de usuario en el Sistema Operativo)

https://developer.apple.com/reference/localauthentication